# Weird C program prefix increment behavior vs. Javascript

Tags: javascript, c

I'm running this simple code snippet:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    /*m = -1
    i = -1
    j = 3
    k = 0*/

    int i = -2, j = 3, k=0, m=0;
    m = ++i || (++j && ++k);
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d", i, j, k, m);
}
```

[image]

My understanding says that `m = ++i` will stop right here and will not evaluate further so value of `i` = value of `m`= -1. However, the value of `m` is 1!

I tried the same code in JavaScript and value of `m` is infact -1 here. What's wrong with the C code?

[image]

Comment: you are using the prefix increment operator which increments the value first and then assigns.

Comment: @hafeez I'm aware of that. That's why I said i = m = -1 finally

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. And Javascript has completely different expression evaluation rules from C.

Comment: *What's wrong with the C code?* **Nothing**. :)

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov I am coming from JavaScript background so for me `-1 || something` is -1 and not 1. I ignored the fact that C will first implicitly cast boolean result to a digit.

Comment: In C a logical expression is never evaluated to anything but `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C, the logical OR operator `||` results in 0 if both arguments evaluate to 0, or 1 if either argument evaluates to non-zero.

In this case, `++i` evaluates to -1, so the right side of `||` is not evaluated and the operator results in 1.

Javascript handles the `||` operator differently.  In particular, it results in the left operand if it evaluates to true, otherwise it results in the right operand.  So you can't expect an operator to work the same way in one language as it does in another.

Comment: Oh!! Coming from JavaScript background, I had the assumption that `-1 || something` is `-1`. But C converts that to boolean value. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

m gets assigned 1 because the result of operator || is typed _Bool, and the expression at the right of assignment is true, which gets casted to integer value of 1 in this case.

Comment: `int`, not `_Bool`.